# Error "from itsdangerous import json as _json ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous'"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On deploying a [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) application to [Google Cloud Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform), I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Exception in worker process from itsdangerous import json as _json ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous'

2022-02-18 08:00:30 default[20220218t132659]  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
  worker.init_process()
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
  super().init_process()
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
  self.load_wsgi()
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
  self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
  self.callable = self.load()
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
  return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
  return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
  mod = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/srv/main.py", line 16, in <module>
  from flask import Flask, render_template,make_response,jsonify, abort, send_from_directory, request, redirect
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  from . import json
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  from itsdangerous import json as _json
ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous' (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Importing itsdangerous.json is deprecated. Import Python’s json module instead.

Answer (score 15):

Flask 1.1.2 is [set up to require *itsdangerous* >= 0.24](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.1.2/setup.py#L58). The latest released (*itsdangerous*) version (2.10) deprecated the JSON API.

To continue using Flask 1.1.2, you need to require at most *itdangerous* 2.0.1 (not 2.10). You can do this by adding

```
itsdangerous==2.0.1
```

...to your *requirements.txt* file (or wherever you list your dependencies).

[*itsdangerous* 2.10 changelog](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/#version-2-1-0)

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same issue and upgraded Flask to version 1.1.4, but then I got:

> 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

This issue seems to be related: *[ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' in Release 1.38.0 #3661](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661)*

Downgrading markupsafe to version 2.0.1 fixed it for me.

Comment: Ran into this same issue. Kept "flask=1.1.2" and specificied "itsdangerous==1.1.0" as per the recommendation here, it worked. 
 https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#pre-installed_packages

Answer (score 9):

Either update [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/changelog/) to `1.1.4`, or fix [itsdangerous](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/) version to `2.0.1`

Comment: Is anyone by any chance also using connexion?  I am, and I see pip using Flask 1.1.4 but the markupsafe problem remains.  Just speculating that it might be from connexion?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem today.

I used Flask in version 1.1.2. The problem disappeared after an update to version 1.1.4.

Comment: I see the markupsafe problem with Flask 1.1.4; maybe I'm using some other package that pins the version differently from what Flask wants?